# How do I set up LoginKit in my own project

Tags: swift, xcode, github, cocoapods

I am currently using LoginKit [github.com/IcaliaLabs/LoginKit](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/LoginKit) to set up my **login** and **signup** screens. I am confused with how to add to my project. (I already have the pods installed and working on the XCWorkspace). If somebody could help me implement this that would be very helpful. If you need screenshots of my project let me know.

Comment: The README at https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/LoginKit looks thorough. What didn't work for you?

Comment: Well first it won't let me import ILLoginKit

Comment: @ConorEbeling Build your app first after adding the pod to the pod file and installing it. Then import ILLoginKit in any of your swift files it will recognized. But importing before giving the app an initial build won't be recognized.